# If carbon has the same structure and properties as silicon(most of them), why can't it be used as a substitute for silicon in semiconductor devices?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Silicon is now the basis for semiconductors and it is used to make all transistors and microprocessors, so why carbon cannot be used as a substitute which is even more abundant and has stronger forces of attraction as with stronger bonds it will be easier to switch on and off the logic gates and hence increasing the speed? Why is it not classified as a semiconductor?

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, silicon is the second most abundant element in Earth's crust -- by mass, we have about a thousand times more of it than we have carbon. _Elemental_ silicon is rarer than elemental carbon (that is, coal), but separating the silicon in rocks from the oxygen it's bound to is a solved problem.

Comment: As an FYI, the vertical columns in the periodic table indicate similarities but there's also a diagonal similarity called the stair step line.   Silicon is a metalloid, Carbon is a non metal.  http://www.chemicalelements.com/groups/metalloids.html   It's kind of interesting reading articles on whether Carbon could be used though because I've found articles that differ on that answer, some say yes, only that it's more difficult, others say no because it's not a semi conductor.    But whether carbon can be used or not, Silicon is far easier to shape into tiny semiconductors and abundant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_diamond#Electronics), appropriately doped diamond can indeed be used as a semiconductor.

But it is a lot cheaper to grow silicon monocrystals than to create synthetic diamonds of comparable size (and there are other manufacturing challenges after the raw crystal has been made), so diamond is currently only interesting for niche applications where silicon won't work.

Non-diamond carbon is generally not crystalline, and so will not work well as a semiconductor.